# Combining unequal data frames and applying a calculation

Tags: r, dataframe, forecasting

I've been doing some data cleaning and regressions but now I would like to apply the output however, I'm stuck on the following problem.

One data frame called "Historical" and looks like this:

```
Year  Value
2014   5
2015   7.5
2016   11
```

The other data frame is called "forecast" and looks like this (new years in the future):

```
Year  Growth
2017   0.05
2018   0.11
```

etc

So I would like to have one data frame to show historical values and forecasted values starting in 2017 (11*1.05)

How can I go about this?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
a <- read.table(header=T, text="Year  Value
2014   5
2015   7.5
2016   11")
b <- read.table(header=T, text="
Year  Growth
2017   0.05
2018   0.11")
```

You could e.g. do

```
rbind(a, cbind(
  Year=b$Year, 
  Value=cumprod(c(tail(a$Value, 1), 1+b$Growth))[-1])
)
#   Year   Value
# 1 2014  5.0000
# 2 2015  7.5000
# 3 2016 11.0000
# 4 2017 11.5500
# 5 2018 12.8205
```